# The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure(SQL) using office 365

Tags: sql-server, sqlmail

I have executed the following.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  @profile_name='Client_Messages',
                                          @from_address= 'Client Automation <messages@client-services.com>',
                                          @recipients='noufal@companynamedomain.com',
                                          @subject='This is a Test mail',
                                          @body='This is a Test mail from Test DB server',@body_format='html';
```

Getting error. some times it worked ,ie; mail executed successfully. sometime error occurred. The error message is given below.

```
Message
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 6 (2021-10-23T17:26:05). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 12.18.126.228:587).
```

Comment: The error message indicates your SMTP server isn't accessible.  Are you sure port 587 is the one you want/need to use?

Comment: Yes. port is 587

Comment: your DB's server may not have priv. to access mail server IP - it was my case back in time

Comment: this issue does not raised everytime. sometime it worked fine without issue. sometime we gets error.

Comment: @Noufalnetspective - Try and run a ping to the machine over a longer period of time (use -t) and see if it at times is unresponsive from that, too.